# What are AI use cases for communication service providers?

Tags: applications

I am currently looking for AI use cases for Telco. What are the different AI use cases for Telcos/communication service providers?

Answer (score 1):

AI could hold the key in automating and optimizing networks. On the subscriber side, ML and AI will assist telecom operators in profiling the subscribers. This will be achieved by analyzing network activity, conversion rate of offers and data usage trends.

Below are a few use cases and how they will transform the telecommunication sector. (Source H2o.ai blog https://www.h2o.ai/telecom/ )

**Old generation telecom technologies.**

1. Reactive Maintenance
2. Network optimization with human intervention
3. Centralized intelligence
4. Security attack repair
5. Backlogged customer tickets

**Future generation AI based telecom technologies.**

1. Predictive Maintenance
2. Self-optimizing network
3. Optimal network quality
4. Intelligence at the edge
5. Security attack prediction
6. Improved customer experience through customer service chat bots.
7. Speech and voice services for customer which allows users to explore media content by spoken word rather than remote control.
8. Predictive maintenance which is the ability to fix problems with telecom hardware such as cell towers, power lines e.t.c before they happen by detecting signals that usually lead to failure.

Answer (score 0):

AI can also be used by Telcos to:
(1) Improve Usage & Retention efforts: Make relevant up-sell and cross-sell offers to the right users at the right time.
(2) Make segmentation more granular: make bespoke recommendations based on a user’s behavioral patterns and content preferences and assessing which call & data packages best suit different customer segments thereby increasing sales success rates

Answer (score 0):

Well AI can be used in Major Areas in Telecom

## 1/ Network Optimization

```
    Where the network is trained to come up with the required Parameter tunning to solve a particular issue, for example in 4G system we have user licenses for cell level that how many users this cell will support. Every time the number of users increases on that cell the Network optimizer sends a work order to the Backoffice to increase the number of users with temporary license that is in pool. For an AI system it can analyze the utilization and increase the licenses or it can tune the parameters to shift traffic on the neighbour cell, it can learn from the optimizers behaviour and actions, this is a single example
```

## 2/ Customer Intelligence

```
     Based on the customer behavior, his social media engagements and responses, usage patterns, past usage history and current context  the AI System can generate personalized offers for the user that can add value to the overall customer Journey and make him and engaged happy customer.
```

## 3/ Network expansions and Dynamic capacity:

```
     Mostly  network operators have licenses per resource contracts with vendors, the excess capacity is charged. In most cases for example in summers some particular areas need more additional capacity but once the summers are gone that particular area is the lowest utilized area. An AI system can learn based on the usage patterns when a particular area need higher capacity and when low capacity and can increase and decrease the capacity resulting in reduced costs.
```

Above are some of the use cases which can further be added with alot of Customer Engagement and Customer Experience Management uses cases

Regards
Muhammad Azfar
Customer Journey and Business Analyst
Customer Experience Management